# calling a function in a controller class

Tags: codeigniter

I a controller class as shown here

```
 <?php if ( ! defined('BASEPATH')) exit('No direct script access allowed');

  class Results extends CI_Controller
   {
    public function index()
   {
    $this->load->model('my_model');       
    }
   function validate()
    {
    //set validation rules here

    //validate form input
    if ($this->form_validation->run() == FALSE) {
        // fails
        $this->load->view('get_results');
    } 
}    
    function ranking1(){
    $data['returned_records']= $this->my_model- >get_ranking();
    $html=$this->load->view('view_ranking', $data, true);       
    $pdfFilePath = "ranking.pdf";        
    $this->load->library('m_pdf');
    //generate the PDF from the given html
    $this->m_pdf->pdf->WriteHTML($html);
    //download it.
    $this->m_pdf->pdf->Output($pdfFilePath, "D");
}    
function top5(){
    $data['returned_records']= $this->school_model->get_top5();       
    $html=$this->load->view('view_top5', $data, true);
    //this the the PDF filename that user will get to download
    $pdfFilePath = "top5.pdf";
    //load mPDF library
    $this->load->library('m_pdf');
    //generate the PDF from the given html
    $this->m_pdf->pdf->WriteHTML($html);

    //download it.
    $this->m_pdf->pdf->Output($pdfFilePath, "D");
    }
  }
```

I want to call these functions from my view like this:

```
  <a href="<?php echo base_url(); ?>results/top5">Top 5</a><br>
        <a href="<?php echo base_url(); ?>results/ranking1">ranking</a><br>
```

when I call the functions in the controller within the **index()** method they work fine but calling them in an **a tag** like shown above does work.

Answer (score 0):

I solved it.It was a stupid mistake. I needed to call **my_model** from the controller's constructor to make the functions access.